# Unknown Facts of Logins Vs Users in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

`Login is Server principle and User is database principle Means we need Login to connect Sql Server and User to access a particular Database , Tables etc

There is a features called Connect Any Database in Sql Server 2014 which allows to give rights of all Db's to a Login I created a New Login and using the Connect Any Database I was able to give Rights of All Db to Login

Now My question is if I can give Database Rights to a Login also why should I Created a User

Refer Below Steps

1) Use Below Script

Create Login Test With Password ='Avengers@012015'

Grant Connect Any DATABASE To Test

2) Create Database One

3)Now Login Using the nelwly created Login Test and type

Use One

and you will see that you are able to connect to the Database one without using Any User

Comment: So it seems to do what it should: "connect to any db" lets you connect to any db. Do you have permissions to read/write?

Comment: I got it it gives the Right of All DB but doesn't allow to create any New Table or Insert a record

Answer (score 0):

Connect Any Database Just allow to connect to any DB it does not give any Write/Read access for which I have to create a User Only